# Read field of chars from BufferReader in Java

Tags: java, stream, char, field

how to read one line of chars in a field of chars in java?

```
private char[] w;
int i=0;

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("pathToFile..."));

char c = '-1';

while (c!='\n') {
    w[i++] = (char) br.read();
}
```

i got
java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally would use an ArrayList here.

```
private List<Character> list = new ArrayList<Character>();

int i=0;

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("pathToFile..."));

char c = '-1';

while (c!='\n') {
    list.add((char) br.read());
}
```

Something like that.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
 private char[] w;

 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("pathToFile..."));

 String s = null;
 // to iterate for each line in file
 while ((s = br.readLine()) !=  null ) {
    // this will store chars of line
    w = s.toCharArray();
   //TODO - do something based on w array

 }
```

Comment: +1 would read a String, and use the String rather than convert to a `char[]`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an instance of the array (in Java, an array is an object -even if the array is of primitive types-)

```
private char[] w = new char[numberBigEnough];
```

Note that I would rather use a more dynamic approach, v.g. using a `StringBuilder` instance. That way you do not have to guess the line's length to specify the array dimensions.